# Emit first Observable, use second Observable as conditional

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I have a ViewModel that is used to update a data model. When a ViewModel property changes, I want to update the relevant property on the data model and save it.

However, this means now I have to be careful. For example, I don't want to save before either model has been loaded. So I've introduced an `IsLoaded` property.

The routine to load the data looks something like this:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    IsLoaded = false;
}

private async Task Load()
{
    IsLoaded = false;

    var UnitAssesment = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
       return App.Repo.GetUnitAssessment( id );
    });

    Title = UnitAssessment.Title;
    Comment = UnitAssessment.Comment;

    IsLoaded = true;
}
```

This sets the properties for the ViewModel initially, then I've setup a 1-way binding from the ViewModel to the data model:

```
this.WhenAnyValue( x => x.Comment )
  .Subscribe( x => {
    if ( !IsLoaded ) return;

    UnitAssessment.Comment = x.Item1;
    SaveUnit();
  });
```

This works, but it's not very succinct for multiple properties. So I started experimenting:

```
this.WhenAnyValue( x => x.Comment, x => x.IsLoaded )
  .Where( x => x.Item2 )
  .Subscribe(x => {
    UnitAssessment.Comment = x.Item1;
    SaveUnit();
  });
```

This is **almost** the same thing. The problem is that the Observable fires when `IsLoaded` is set to true. Which causes the data model to re-save with the same data.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
var isNotLoaded = this.WhenAnyValue( x => x.IsLoaded ).Where( x => !x );

this.WhenAnyValue( x => x.Comment )
  .ExceptWhen( isNotLoaded )
  .ToProperty(this, x => x.UnitAssessment.Comment );

PropertyChanged += ( sender, e ) => SaveUnit();
```

Either that or monitor 2 Observables, but only fire when the first one changes. Is there anything like this in Rx.NET? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to use the [`WithLatestFrom()`](http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom) function. It acts like [`CombineLatest()`](http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest), but instead of emitting the result whenever a new value is received from either source, it only emits results when a new value is received from a single source.

For example:

```
// The observable that we want the latest value from
var isLoaded = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IsLoaded);

// Setup a new observable that watches for changes
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Comment)

    // Combine it with the most recent value from the above observable
    .WithLatestFrom(isLoaded, (comment, loaded) => new { comment, loaded })

    // Filter for when we're loaded
    .Where(x => x.loaded)

    // Side-effects
    .Select(x => x.comment)
    .Do(comment => {
      UnitAssessment.Comment = comment;
      SaveUnit();
    })

    // Make sure that everything happens
    .Subscribe();
```

I wasn't able to find easily available API docs for the specific C# function, but I was able to find the source:

- [WithLatestFrom Source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/46db85a65c1fab701284bf6bc71e39df54287c83/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable.Multiple.cs#L1518)
- [CombineLatest Source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/46db85a65c1fab701284bf6bc71e39df54287c83/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable.Multiple.cs#L208)

Comment: I tried installing the NuGet package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive.Linq/). However, the library doesn't install for my PCL/Xamarin Forms library. Which is a shame

Comment: You should install [Rx-Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/rx-linq/2.2.5) in case you're still using ReactiveUI 7.4 or lower, you should have it automatically if you install the correct ReactiveUI version in your PCL.